# Prevent numeric input in string in C

Tags: string, validation

```
char name[50];
int valid;

do{
      valid=1;
      printf("Enter name for Salesman: ");
      fgets(name,50,stdin);
      if(!isalpha(*name)) //it will only scan for the first character of string
      {
          printf("Only alphabet is allowed.\n");
          valid=0;
      }
  }while(valid==0);
```

I want the whole string doesn't have any numeric input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to process the entire string:

```
int i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < strlen(name) && i < 50; i++) {
  if (!isalpha(name[i])) {
    valid = 0;
    printf("Please only use alphabetic characters!\n");
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't C language support regular expression like java does ?

so we can do it in java like this :

```
String test= "Any String even if 1 digit is in between";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+");

Matcher m = p.matcher(test);

if (m.find())
{               
    System.out.println("Numeric is not allowed");
}
```